# Is there a way to use the AR module in nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use the `nativescript-ar` plugin as outlined in [this tutorial](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/getting-started-with-augmented-reality-in-nativescript), but I'm using Vue instead of Angular. For whatever reason, I can't get the AR module view to render.

These are some ways I've tried to import the component:

```js
import {
  AR,
  ARLoadedEventData,
  ARNodeInteraction,
  ARPlaneTappedEventData
} from "nativescript-ar";
import { Color } from "tns-core-modules/color";

export default {
  components: {
    // AR: () => require("nativescript-ar").AR
    // AR: () => import("nativescript-ar").AR
    AR
  },
```

I'm also testing the app using `tns preview` rather than `tns run ios` - is that an issue in of itself? I feel like I've tried every combination of "hacks" so far to no avail...

Comment: Find that example in vue here https://github.com/ebellumat/ar-native

Comment: Thanks for that link - I will give that a shot later tonight to see if it works! I see that you registered the AR component at `main.js` rather than in the `.vue` components themselves. Do you know if this will be able to be previewed using the `tns preview` command and the playground app on iOS, or does this need to get built directly to an iOS device?

Comment: @PetrMitev Vue or Angular, end of the day it's just a framework that manipulates on UI components / HTML DOM (Web). So almost all the plugins should work seamlessly on both Angular / Vue. If you still have issues, please explain the issue in detail. Regarding `tns preview`, it works only with limited set of plugins and AR is not one of them.